# How can I remove the carriage return from this bash output?

Tags: php, bash

I am trying to build a simple environment detection script in php using a call to to bash shell

```
<?php

$env = shell_exec('localhost');

if ($env == 'trusty-ssd') {
    // do environment specific setup here 
}
```

The problem is the output of the `localhost` command seems to have a new line character, e.g.

```
var_dump($env)
```

> string 'trusty-ssd
>   ' (length=11)

and therefore the `if ($env == 'trusty-ssd')` condition isnt met.
I have tried

```
$env = str_replace('\r', '', $env);
```

also tried `\n` as the search string.

but the `if ($env == 'trusty-ssd')` condtion still isnt being met.
.
How can I remove the end of line character from `localhost` either using bash or PHP?

Comment: `trim()` should do it.

Comment: have you tried `trim()`

Comment: @Dagon `rtrim` did it. I knew `trim` - without optional args - removed whitespace, I didnt know it removed several other non-visible characters as well. thanks!